# Duplicate (filter) id of inline SVG

Tags: html, dom, svg

When creating an inline SVG with filters, I have to define an ID for the filter.

When I automatically generates several inline SVG with slight differences, **the filter of the first image prevails (overwrites) the filter of the following images** (because of **duplicate filters ID**).

Live demo, far more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/9wqgS/

```
<p>Image 1 Hue = 100</p><p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="120">
  <filter id="colorchangerfilter" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <feColorMatrix id="huefilter" type = "hueRotate" values = "100"/>
  </filter>
  <image 
xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/archive/6/6e/20110118171033%21HTML5-logo.svg/120px-HTML5-logo.svg.png" width="120" height="120" filter="url(#colorchangerfilter)"/>
</svg>
</p><br>

<p>Image 2 Hue = 200</p><p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="120">
  <filter id="colorchangerfilter" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <feColorMatrix id="huefilter" type = "hueRotate" values = "200"/>
  </filter>
  <image 
xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/archive/6/6e/20110118171033%21HTML5-logo.svg/120px-HTML5-logo.svg.png" width="120" height="120" filter="url(#colorchangerfilter)"/>
</svg>
</p>
```

Image 1 should be green (hue=100) and image 2 should be blue (hue=200). Instead, both images are green.

I send below a workaround to this issue but I really would like to have a simpler solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The workaround is to **generate a unique or random filter ID for each SVG.**

```
<p>Image 1 Hue = 100</p><p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="120">
  <filter id="colorchangerfilter-green" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <feColorMatrix id="huefilter" type = "hueRotate" values = "100"/>
  </filter>
  <image 
xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/archive/6/6e/20110118171033%21HTML5-logo.svg/120px-HTML5-logo.svg.png" width="120" height="120" filter="url(#colorchangerfilter-green)"/>
</svg>
</p><br>

<p>Image 2 Hue = 200</p><p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="120">
  <filter id="colorchangerfilter-blue" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
    <feColorMatrix id="huefilter" type = "hueRotate" values = "200"/>
  </filter>
  <image 
xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/archive/6/6e/20110118171033%21HTML5-logo.svg/120px-HTML5-logo.svg.png" width="120" height="120" filter="url(#colorchangerfilter-blue)"/>
</svg>
</p>
```

That may sound simple but for me it's very unpractical. I would like to have a solution without filter IDs (I don't think this is possible) or with duplicate ID but without prevalence (maybe embedded into something?).

Comment: What you describe may become possible in the future, see https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/masking/index.html#the-clip-path (the `child` keyword), but isn't yet implemented in browsers. So, right now you need to generate unique ID's for this to work.