# SVG turns black when cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, clone

I was playing with the [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function from jQuery when I found out a strange behavior.

This code reproduces the problem. A first div contains an SVG. Two buttons allows doing/undoing a clone of the SVG into a second div. Trying it two times makes the circle to turn black.

[image] [image]

#### HTML

```
<div id="orgdiv">
    <svg width="200" height="200" style="margin:0">
        <linearGradient  id="r" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#00ffff"></stop>
            <stop  offset="100%" stop-color="#ffff00"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" style="fill:url(#r)" />
    </svg>
</div>

<input type="button" value="copy">
<input type="button" value="clear">

<div id="copydiv"></div>
```

#### JS

```
$('input[value="copy"]').click(function(){
    $("#copydiv").html($("#orgdiv").clone());
});

$('input[value="clear"]').click(function(){
    $("#copydiv").empty();
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2K4xv/)</kbd>

#### Note:

- cloning with jQuery or Javascript leads to the same bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matt Gibson presents a hack: drumming up new ids and then having duplicated html with redundant `linearGradient` definitions referencing the original `linearGradient`.

Happily, you do you need to do this ;)

Part of the strength of the `svg` tags is that they're their own mad little containers. so you can reference stuff externally from an uri.

&So if you're in the cloning business, then instead of worrying about ids, you can abstract out the template model & re-use it ad-infinitum:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[value="copy"]').click(function () {
      $("#copydiv").append($(":first", "#orgdiv").clone());
  });

  $('input[value="clear"]').click(function () {
      $("#copydiv").empty();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- ------------------- platonic horse ------------------------- -->
<div style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute; width:0">
  <svg>
    <g id="my-funky-svg-defs">
   <defs>
     <radialGradient id="gradient" cx="25%" cy="25%" r="100%" fx="40%" fy="40%">
    <stop offset=  "0%" stop-color="hsla(313,  80%, 80%, 1)"/>
    <stop offset= "40%" stop-color="hsla(313, 100%, 65%, 1)"/>
    <stop offset="110%" stop-color="hsla(313, 100%, 50%, 0.7)"/>
     </radialGradient>
   </defs>    
   <title>smarteee</title>
   <circle  class="face" cx="200" cy="200" r="195" fill="url(#gradient)" />
   <ellipse class="eye eye-left" cx="140" cy="150" rx="10" ry="40" fill="#131313"/>
   <ellipse class="eye eye-right" cx="260" cy="150" rx="10" ry="40" fill="#131313"/>
   <path class="smile" d="M120,280 Q200,330 280,280" stroke-width="10" stroke="#131313" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </g>
  </svg> 
</div>

<!-- ---------------------- prototype ----------------------- ---- -->
proto
<input type="button" value="copy"/>
<hr/>
<div id="orgdiv">
    <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="margin:20px;">
        <use xlink:href="#my-funky-svg-defs"></use>
    </svg>
</div>

<!-- ------------------------- clones ----------------------- ---- -->
clones
<input type="button" value="clear"/>
<hr/>
<div id="copydiv"></div>
```

Also [here's a fork of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e17pc6g6/).

Answer (score 7):

I have a hunch it may be because you're cloning the linearGradient, which has an `id` attribute (which should, of course, be unique throughout the document.) This might be confusing the SVG processor.

My theory seems to be borne out by changing the ID on the way through the clone:

```
$('input[value="copy"]').click(function () {
    var clone = $("#orgdiv").clone();
    // Change the ID of the clone, so we don't have duplicate IDs
    clone.find("#r").attr('id', 'unique');
    $("#copydiv").html(clone);
});
```

...which appears to prevent the problem. (In this case the clone still gets a gradient even though the ID of its cloned gradient has changed, because it's finding the original gradient by its ID.)

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2K4xv/2/

I'm guessing that what's happening "under the hood" in your case is that the processor is picking up the second gradient filter element that you're creating for use with the first circle, and then losing its reference to it when it's destroyed by your `empty()`, thus leaving you with the circle but no gradient. Exactly why this only happens second time through is probably down to the implementation details of the SVG renderer's interactions with the HTML5 document.

There's more information on this issue in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497168/duplicate-filter-id-of-inline-svg).

Comment: That answers the question. Thank you! That might also explain why [hiding and showing again the original SVG](http://jsfiddle.net/2K4xv/3/) could also solve the problem, because of the same reason: the `#r` disappeared and needed to be initialized again!

Answer (score 2):

Once you clone it you have two elements with an id of "r", one in the original and one in the clone. All ids must be unique so the document is no longer valid.

Comment: Thank you!! I was having essentially the same problem as in original question.  I had two div's that used the same gradient. I show/hide of them, while the other is always visible.  After a hiding/showing the 2nd dive a couple times, the gradient goes black on the always visible div. I show the 2nd div, everything's fine.  I hide it and the gradient on the 1st div goes black.  Now I add an extra bit of text to the gradient's id based on a string that's passed in to the constructor.  Now the gradient stays!!  Thanks so much Bill