# Restrict Inline SVG's ID's to SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, inline-svg

Is it possible to restrict ids in an inline svg to the svg only?

E.g

```
<svg width="660" height="220">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#05a"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0a5"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="10" y="10" width="600" height="200" fill="url(#linear)" />
</svg>
```

Here this has created a global id "linear" on the page.

How can I prevent this?

I.e I want `document.getElementById("linear")` to return `undefined`.

Or is there another mechanism to reference items within an svg so that I can apply a gradient without having to use ID's?

---

Related: [Duplicate (filter) id of inline SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497168/duplicate-filter-id-of-inline-svg)

Comment: Move the svg into a separate file and access it via an object, iframe or image tag.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks but I want it to be inline so that I can change the gradient with css.

Comment: you could inject the css via javascript through the object or iframe into the child document if you wanted.